# Ember CLI async initializers & cordova readiness

Tags: javascript, cordova, ember.js, ember-cli

Using ember cli v0.1.4, ember 1.8.1 & cordova 3.7, I'm utilizing initializers to wait for the device to be ready;

```
var CordovaInitializer = {
  name: 'waitForCordova',
  before:'i18n',

  initialize: function(Container, App) {

    if(window.cordova) {
      console.log('defering app launch until cordova is ready...');
      App.deferReadiness();

      document.addEventListener('deviceready', function(){
        console.log('lift off!');

        App.advanceReadiness();
      }, false);
    }
  }
};

export default CordovaInitializer;
```

My second initialzer needs to wait for cordova app readiness too -

```
export default {
  name: 'i18n',
  after:'waitForCordova',

  initialize: function(Container, App) {

     console.log('initializing translations'); 

     /* snip */
  } 

};
```

I am expecting the following output -

```
$ defering app launch until cordova is ready...
$ lift off!
$ initializing translations
```

However, I am getting the following -

```
$ defering app launch until cordova is ready...
$ initializing translations
$ lift off!
```

How can I get my second initializer to wait until cordova is loaded? They're firing in the correct order, but I was expecting the second one to wait for `App.advanceReadiness`.

Essentially I need an async initializers as described here - [ember initializers](http://nerdyworm.com/blog/2013/04/03/ember-initializers/) followed by a second adapter that waits for the first to complete.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### **Note: This answer was updated. Check the update below**

**========================Old Answer=========================**

You can utilize [Ember.Instrumentation](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Instrumentation.html) to sync your initializers

```js
// app/initializers/cordova.js

import Ember from 'ember';

var CordovaInitializer = {
  name: 'waitForCordova',
  before: 'i18n',
  initialize: function(container, application) {
    application.set('shouldSubscribeCordovaDeviceReady', false);
    if (window.cordova) {
      console.log('defering app launch until cordova is ready...');

      application.set('shouldSubscribeCordovaDeviceReady', true);
      application.deferReadiness();

      document.addEventListener('deviceready', function() {
        console.log('lift off!');
        Ember.Instrumentation.instrument('cordova:deviceready', null, Ember.K);
        application.set('shouldSubscribeCordovaDeviceReady', false);
        application.advanceReadiness();
      }, false);
    }
  }
};

export
default CordovaInitializer;
```

```js
// app/initializers/i18n.js

import Ember from 'ember';

var initializeI18n = function(container, application) {
  console.log('initializing translations');
  //do your thing
};

export
default {
  name: 'i18n',
  after: 'waitForCordova',
  initialize: function(container, application) {
    var subscriber;
    if (application.get('shouldSubscribeCordovaDeviceReady')) {
      application.deferReadiness();
      subscriber = Ember.Instrumentation.subscribe('cordova:deviceready', {
        before: Ember.K,
        after: function() {
          initializeI18n(container, app);
          application.advanceReadiness();
          Ember.Instrumentation.unsubscribe(subscriber);
        }
      });
    } else {
      initializeI18n(container, application);
    }
  }
};
```

**========================End of Old Answer====================**

### **===================Updated Answer===================**

In order to sync your initializers, you can extend the Ember.Application class with [Ember.Evented](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Evented.html). In this way, the `application` instance will have [pubsub](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Publish%E2%80%93subscribe_pattern) capabilities.

```js
// app/app.js

import Ember from 'ember';

// ...

var App;

App = Ember.Application.extend(Ember.Evented, {

  // ...  

});

// ...

export default App;
```

```js
// app/initializers/cordova.js

import Ember from 'ember';

var CordovaInitializer = {
  name: 'waitForCordova',
  before: 'i18n',
  initialize: function(registry, application) {
    application.set('shouldSubscribeCordovaDeviceReady', false);
    if (window.cordova) {
      console.log('defering app launch until cordova is ready...');

      application.set('shouldSubscribeCordovaDeviceReady', true);
      application.deferReadiness();

      document.addEventListener('deviceready', function() {
        console.log('lift off!');
        application.trigger('cordova:deviceready');
        application.set('shouldSubscribeCordovaDeviceReady', false);
        application.advanceReadiness();
      }, false);
    }
  }
};

export
default CordovaInitializer;
```

```js
// app/initializers/i18n.js

import Ember from 'ember';

var initializeI18n = function(container, application) {
  console.log('initializing translations');
  //do your thing
};

export
default {
  name: 'i18n',
  after: 'waitForCordova',
  initialize: function(registry, application) {
    if (application.get('shouldSubscribeCordovaDeviceReady')) {
      application.deferReadiness();
      application.one('cordova:deviceready', null, function() {
        initializeI18n(container, app);
        application.advanceReadiness();
      });
    } else {
      initializeI18n(container, application);
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: hmm that's interesting, but if I were to go down that route I might be tempted to just merge the two initializers together

Comment: I am personally, a sucker for decoupling :). It really depends whether your Cordova initializer should really do something beside triggering the i18n initializer. If this is the case I would recommend using the Instrumentation mechanism. Otherwise, you are right and you can do it in one initializer.

Comment: Also, maybe in the future you will have more modules to initialize after Cordova is ready and then you could init them in this way too. So each module will have its own initializer

Comment: Yeah I'm all for decoupling too, will have to give it a go and see how noisy it looks within the app as a whole. Thanks for your suggestion :)